# How to Use Laravel Query Builder with and Where Clause in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I am trying to ensure that a record exists in the database before performing a user-related action. When I execute the query directly in my PHPMyAdmin like so (for testing purposes).

```
SELECT * FROM `chat_participants` WHERE `chat_id` = 2 AND `user_id` = 2
```

I receive the correct record. However, when I try to use the Laravel Query Builder to achieve the same.

```php
dd($this->participants
    ->where('chat_id', '=', 2)
    ->where('user_id', '=', 2)
    ->get()
    ->first());
```

I get `null.` Is there a way I can ensure that the record exists in the database using Query Builder? Do I need to declare `AND` in the Query Builder?

Update: I set the `participants` variable in my constructor.

```php
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->header = DB::table('chat_headers');
    $this->participants = DB::table('chat_participants');
    $this->messages = DB::table('chat_messages');
}
```

toSql() produces:

```
select * from chat_participants` 
    inner join chat_headers on chat_headers.id = chat_participants.chat_id 
    inner join chat_rbac on chat_rbac.id = chat_participants.rbac 
 where chat_participants.chat_id = ? and chat_participants.user_id = ? 
    and chat_id = ? and user_id = ?
```

Comment: What is the `participants` property here?

Comment: Updated question to show @Devon

Comment: Do `$this->participants->where('chat_id', '=', 2)->where('user_id', '=', 2)->toSql()` to see what SQL query is being generated. Multiple `where()` calls are automatically `AND`ed together. Side note: `->get()->first()` can just be `->first()`.

Comment: `->get()->first()` is redundant btw; `->get()` will return a `Collection` of records that match your query, followed by `->first()` will return the first of those records. You can simply use `->first()` to save some calculation time.

Comment: `"select * from `chat_participants` inner join `chat_headers` on `chat_headers`.`id` = `chat_participants`.`chat_id` inner join `chat_rbac` on `chat_rbac`.`id` = `chat_participants`.`rbac` where `chat_participants`.`chat_id` = ? and `chat_participants`.`user_id` = ? and `chat_id` = ? and `user_id` = ?` @ceejayoz

Comment: @Jaquarh Huh? That's a totally different query. None of the code you're showing does a JOIN.

Comment: I know, this has confused me too! I use `$this->participants` multiple times so maybe it is remembering its state from before... Perhaps I need to use `DB::table('chat_participants')` rather than `$this->participants` ? @ceejayoz

Comment: @Jaquarh, you must be manipulating the participants property elsewhere before reaching this line, or you have the wrong line here.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that when I use `$this->participants` earlier on, it remembers all of the joins I used. Perhaps I need to use `DB::table()` again? @Devon

Comment: Perhaps, I don't know your project or why you're using the same query object over and over again, but yes, objects are always passed as reference in PHP, so of course it will remember the state.

Comment: @Jaquarh Yes, if other code uses the same `$this->participants` variable their various joins and wheres and whatnot will still be there. Start with a fresh query builder.

Comment: I always thought you needed to use `&=` to pass by reference? Feel free to make this an answer with that explanation @Devon and I'll accept. Thanks for the help both! @ceejayoz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects are passed by reference in PHP, this means you're passing a pointer to the same Query Builder object everywhere you use the `participants` property.  So in most cases, you would want to instantiate a new query builder object for each query.

However, PHP does allow for cloning of objects, which would allow you to pass a base query builder and start fresh **everywhere** you use it:

```
$query = clone $this->participants;
$query->where(..)->first();
```

This is an implementation of the Prototype OO pattern, build up a base object and then create a copy of it to do the specifics.

This would be just one way you could avoid hard-coding your table name everywhere you query it.

Comment: Thank you for this information! You realised the concept of making participants a property to save constantly writing `DB::table()`. I had no clue you could use the `clone` keyword like so!